# Can i get the filename like #[header:originalFilename] in a component in mule3

Tags: file, mule

I use

```
<gzip-compress-transformer/>
<base64-encoder-transformer/>
```

after a file connector, and then write a component to deal with the gzip+base64 content.
How can i get the file name in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we introduced annotations in Mule 3 for doing runtime injection, this means you can specify how to invoke a component without needing transformers i.e.

public void save(@Payload String fileContents, @InboundHeaders("originalFilename") String originalFilename)

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Creating+Service+Objects+and+Transformers+Using+Annotations

Comment: This is a great approach. Unfortunately, the OP didn't specify if it was OK or not for his component to be Mule-aware or not. My proposal to use a transformer was really in case he wanted to keep his component Mule-free, which IMO is another selling point of Mule (its capacity to work with any pre-existing object).

Comment: good point, we should really break out the annotations into their own jar so that would be the only dependency.  Maybe even that is too much for some

Comment: Or go the Spring way: start first with custom annotations and whenever a standard one can fit, switch to it supporting both the Mule-custom and the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

Does your component implement [Callable](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.1.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/lifecycle/Callable.html)? If not, do you want to keep your component Mule-unaware?

Based on your answers to these questions, different options exist:

- With Callable, you get the headers in message.getProperty...
- Without implementing Callable, you can access RequestContext to get the current Mule event and from there reach the message properties. But this makes your component Mule aware.
- Otherwise, have your component's method take a second parameter (String originalFilename) and use a standard expression transformer to transform the payload in an array that contains: #payload, #[header:originalFilename]. This arrays will then be passed as arguments to your component's method.

Comment: I can get file name using context.getMessage().getOutboundProperty("originalFilename"), but now i need directory information, I set "recursive" to true, can I get the directory information from Header or Property? Or need I set "autoDelete" to false, and access the java.io.File object?

Comment: No, the transport won't add directory information. You can build a File object out of originalFilename.

Answer (score 0):

[message.outboundproperties[originalFilename]]

with this expression you can  get the original file name in the component.